# sum column based on two matching fields using awk

Tags: awk

I can't seem find an awk solution for this simple task. I can easily sum a column ($3) based on one matching field ($1) with :

```
awk -F, '{array[$1]+=$3} END { for (i in array) {print i"," array[i]}}' datas.csv
```

Now, how can I do that based on two fields ? Lets say $1 and $2 ? Here is a sample datas :

```
P1,gram,10  
P1,tree,12  
P1,gram,34  
P2,gram,23  
...
```

I simply need to sum column 3 if first and second fields match.

Thanx for any help !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like so

```
awk -F, '{array[$1","$2]+=$3} END { for (i in array) {print i"," array[i]}}' datas.csv
```

My result

```
P1,tree,12
P1,gram,44
P2,gram,23
```

**EDIT**

As the OP needs the commas to remain in the output, I edited the answer above using @yi_H's "comma fix".

Comment: thanks for your answer Ray Toal, but I already tried this solution and it doesn't meet my need, in fact I really need to keep my fields separated for further processing...

Comment: @yi_H's fix preserves the three-column output; answer edited.

Comment: This needs lots of memory on a large file.

Comment: Nice observation, @jfgagne.  On a large file one would use `sort`.  And with tens of gigabytes time for mapreduce. :)

Answer (score 1):

For a solution needing less memory, but needing sorting first (nothing is free):

```
sort datas.csv | awk -F "," 'NR==1{last=$1 "," $2; sum=0;}{if (last != $1 "," $2) {print last "," sum; last=$1 "," $2; sum=0;} sum += $3;}END{print last "," sum;}'
```