# Gawk distinct and sum column

Tags: arrays, csv, awk, sum, gawk

I am very new to linux and the usage of awk and couldn't find an answer for my following question:

I want to use awk and my file is structured like that:

```
Date ID Size
2016-11-09 688 47
2016-11-09 688 56
2016-11-09 31640 55
```

Now I want to sum up the size for each line that has the Date and ID and export it to a .csv file.
The file should look like that:

```
Date,ID,Size
2016-11-09,688,103
2016-11-09,31640 55
```

I really need your help, because I could not figure out how to do it on my own, thank you.

Comment: please do show some effort on solving it. Did you try finding similar questions and testing their answers?

Comment: You sure you want to do something like this in bash or awk?  You could use SQL which was designed for this type of stuff.

Comment: I would know how to this in SQL but I can't in this case because the file is too big.
Sure I did try to solve it but I could only put the fields in an array by now and separate them by using a for loop. Now I have something like :
688 2016-11-10 44
1661 2016-11-09 46
31640 2016-11-09 55
1661 2016-11-10 46
688 2016-11-09 44

Comment: @JohnDro possible duplicate, take a look here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970041/sum-column-based-on-two-matching-fields-using-awk

Comment: @dood you are right, I couldn't find that one, but it is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much :)

Comment: Just because a script produces the expected output given some input that doesn't mean it's the right solution for you. You said your input file is huge. The answer given in that "duplicate" question stores the entire contents in memory. That's completely unnecessary if your input is sorted by date and ID as the small sample you posted is. Is that always the case?

Comment: @EdMorton Wouldn't doing things in memory make it faster?  Plus the code in that solution is simple and very easy to read.

Comment: Not in this case. That script is reading the file one line at a time, saving it in an array, then later reading each line in the array, and doing calculations. The script in my answer is reading the file one line at a time and doing calculations. It just doesn't need to do the 2 middle steps. The net result is improved efficiency, far less memory usage, and an output order that's the same as the input order. Easy to read doesn't necessarily mean easy to understand - I don't think you understood the implications of using that code.

Comment: @EdMorton That makes sense Ed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your input is really sorted by date and ID as in your sample then you should use this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
NR==1 { $1=$1; print; next }
{ curr = $1 OFS $2 }
(curr != prev) && (NR > 2) { print prev, sum; sum=0 }
{ prev = curr; sum += $3 }
END { print prev, sum }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Date,ID,Size
2016-11-09,688,103
2016-11-09,31640,55
```

rather than saving the whole file in memory. Note that this approach will also produce output in the same order as the input whereas any `for .. in ..` loop in an `END` section will print the output in random (hash) order.

Comment: Fixed the `OFS` array subscript, issue, still dealing with the hard-coding part `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}NR=1{print;next}{k=$1 OFS $2; a[k]+=$3}END{for (i in a) {print i,a[i]}}' file` ain't working,

Comment: Add `$1=$1;` before the first `print` so awk recompiles the current record using OFS between the fields. Make it `NR==1` (double `=`) too so it's a comparison rather than assignment. Basically make it exactly what I have in my script, `NR==1 { $1=$1; print; next }`.

Comment: Realised that and will keep in mind, so didn't want to post a badly constructed solution of your good one! :)